# how to generate v93k pattern in quad or dual mode?

Tags: origen-sdk

Hi all:  Does Origen support dual or quad mode in V93K?

I tried origen g bistcom --quad / origen g bistcom --dual/ origen g bistcom_mmquad

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

@thaohuynh I dont think this is supported in OrigenTesters for v93k style testers.  Please submit a new issue at : https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/issues.